# Is it possible to profile with android studio when using flutter release mode?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, profile

If I run `flutter --profile`, then I can profile my app in android studio. But when I start with `flutter --release` command, Android Studio does not show me a device for profiling. Andoird studio then tells me "No debuggable processes".
Can I force Android studio to also profile my app in release mode? (I'm only interested in CPU and memory usage).

[image]

Comment: i also now added `android:debuggable="true"` for release mode, but it still did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of profile mode is to let you check on those things specifically. (CPU and memory usage as well as other things). if you check the [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes#profile) they say:

> profile mode is similar to release mode, with the following differences:
>
> - Some service extensions, such as the one that enables the performance overlay, are enabled.
> - Tracing is enabled, and tools supporting source-level debugging (such as DevTools) can connect to the process.

In other words profile is running as close to release as possible while still giving you the ability to check performance metrics/ find out what is causing  performance issues.

If you really need the exact cpu and memory then you can run the app in release mode through xcode. Here are the steps to do that:

1. open Runner.xcworkspace
2. In the top bar, click Runner > edit scheme. This should open up a new window
3. In the new window, click Run > info > Build Configuration > Release
4. Close the window and run the app on your device by clicking the Play button
5. You can see the CPU and Memory in the left side bar under the Debug tab (It looks like an aerosol can to me)
   [image]

Comment: Yes thank you, however I would like to test it in release mode. I ony neet the CPU and memory usage. The more specific details do not interest me.

Comment: @Sud0 See the updated answer. If you have time, I'm curious if there's any noticeable difference in cpu/ memory in profile vs release

Comment: thanks for your help, actually exactly what I need. But for xcode profiling i need an iphone if i want to test it on a device isn´t? Unfortunately I do not own one :/

Comment: You can check these out: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/find-whats-eating-up-your-ram-android-0286762/  https://mobileinternist.com/cpu-usage-android  Let me know if that works and I'll update my answer with them

Comment: @Sud0 Any updates?